# After upgrading the kernel, the sound no longer works

Tags: debian, kernel, audio, upgrade, pulseaudio

I have updated the Linux kernel on my system to `Linux  3.11-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.11.10-1 (2013-12-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Having done that, the sound no longer works.

**Distribution Info**(`cat /etc/*-release`):

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux jessie/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
ID=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.debian.org/"
```

When I run the command `lspci | grep -i audio` it prints the following:

```
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler HDMI Audio
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
```

When I try to do a test of my sound with the command:

```
 LC_ALL=C speaker-test -l 3 -t sine -c 1
```

I get the following:

```
speaker-test 1.0.27.2

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Sine wave rate is 440.0000Hz
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Access denied

Playback open error: -111,Connection refused
```

What should I do?

When I run the command `alsactl init` it prints:

```
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "ATI R6xx HDMI" "HDA:1002aa01,00aa0100,00100200" "0x1025" "0x0740"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

So when I try to run: `pulseaudio -D` it prints:

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

**aplay -l**

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC271X Analog [ALC271X Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**aplay -L**

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
hdmi:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
sysdefault:CARD=Generic_1
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC271X Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC271X Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC271X Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC271X Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC271X Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC271X Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Generic_1,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC271X Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
```

**dmesg | grep sound**

```
[    8.838666] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/sound/card0/input7
[    9.395442] input: HD-Audio Generic Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card1/input10
[    9.395704] input: HD-Audio Generic Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card1/input11
```

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cpufreq_userspace      12525  0 
cpufreq_stats          12777  0 
cpufreq_powersave      12454  0 
cpufreq_conservative    14184  0 
parport_pc             26300  0 
ppdev                  12686  0 
lp                     17074  0 
parport                35749  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
bnep                   17431  2 
rfcomm                 36903  0 
bluetooth             215917  10 bnep,rfcomm
binfmt_misc            16949  1 
nfsd                  255063  2 
auth_rpcgss            51036  1 nfsd
oid_registry           12419  1 auth_rpcgss
nfs_acl                12511  1 nfsd
nfs                   143940  0 
lockd                  79321  2 nfs,nfsd
fscache                45230  1 nfs
sunrpc                211258  6 nfs,nfsd,auth_rpcgss,lockd,nfs_acl
fuse                   78616  1 
loop                   26609  0 
uvcvideo               78960  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      12816  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       12519  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         35029  1 uvcvideo
videodev              105100  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
media                  18303  2 uvcvideo,videodev
joydev                 17063  0 
acer_wmi               30174  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    41059  1 
arc4                   12536  2 
sparse_keymap          12818  1 acer_wmi
ath9k                  94801  0 
radeon               1166155  3 
ath9k_common           12687  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              390315  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    21417  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              416244  1 ath9k
ttm                    69419  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper         35647  1 radeon
drm                   227730  5 ttm,drm_kms_helper,radeon
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     35769  1 
snd_hda_intel          39672  7 
snd_hda_codec         142551  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
kvm                   354353  0 
i2c_piix4              12623  0 
cfg80211              377915  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211
snd_hwdep              13148  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                84096  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         17114  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
pcspkr                 12595  0 
psmouse                82028  0 
evdev                  17445  24 
serio_raw              12849  0 
k10temp                12618  0 
snd_seq                48834  0 
snd_seq_device         13132  1 snd_seq
snd_timer              26614  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
i2c_algo_bit           12751  1 radeon
snd                    60869  23 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
wmi                    17339  1 acer_wmi
rfkill                 18978  6 cfg80211,acer_wmi,bluetooth
i2c_core               24084  6 drm,i2c_piix4,drm_kms_helper,i2c_algo_bit,radeon,videodev
acpi_cpufreq           17299  0 
mperf                  12411  1 acpi_cpufreq
soundcore              13026  1 snd
processor              28326  3 acpi_cpufreq
video                  17844  1 acer_wmi
ac                     12668  0 
battery                13101  0 
button                 12944  0 
ext4                  457329  1 
crc16                  12343  2 ext4,bluetooth
mbcache                13034  1 ext4
jbd2                   82560  1 ext4
sg                     29971  0 
sd_mod                 44300  3 
crc_t10dif             12348  1 sd_mod
microcode              30309  0 
ehci_pci               12472  0 
thermal                17468  0 
thermal_sys            27268  3 video,thermal,processor
ohci_pci               12808  0 
ohci_hcd               25977  1 ohci_pci
ahci                   25096  2 
libahci                27121  1 ahci
ehci_hcd               44263  1 ehci_pci
xhci_hcd               89949  0 
libata                169120  2 ahci,libahci
usbcore               154086  6 uvcvideo,ohci_hcd,ohci_pci,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,xhci_hcd
scsi_mod              178166  3 sg,libata,sd_mod
usb_common             12440  1 usbcore
r8169                  60070  0 
mii                    12675  1 r8169
```

**grep -i pulse /var/log/syslog**

```
Dec 20 13:43:39 Demian pulseaudio[3565]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 13:43:39 Demian pulseaudio[3565]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 13:43:41 Demian pulseaudio[3631]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 13:43:41 Demian pulseaudio[3631]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 13:46:52 Demian pulseaudio[3731]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 13:46:52 Demian pulseaudio[3731]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 13:46:54 Demian pulseaudio[3735]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 13:46:54 Demian pulseaudio[3735]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 15:59:58 Demian pulseaudio[3736]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 15:59:58 Demian pulseaudio[3736]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 15:59:59 Demian pulseaudio[3739]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 15:59:59 Demian pulseaudio[3739]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 16:00:57 Demian pulseaudio[3945]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Dec 20 16:11:57 Demian pulseaudio[3762]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 16:11:57 Demian pulseaudio[3762]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 16:11:59 Demian pulseaudio[3767]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 16:11:59 Demian pulseaudio[3767]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 16:13:47 Demian pulseaudio[3973]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Dec 20 18:06:15 Demian pulseaudio[3911]: [pulseaudio] module-x11-publish.c: PulseAudio information vanished from X11!
Dec 20 20:15:22 Demian pulseaudio[3726]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 20:15:22 Demian pulseaudio[3726]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 20:15:24 Demian pulseaudio[3731]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 20:15:24 Demian pulseaudio[3731]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 20:20:36 Demian pulseaudio[3673]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 20:20:36 Demian pulseaudio[3673]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 20:20:37 Demian pulseaudio[3705]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 20:20:37 Demian pulseaudio[3705]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 21:36:34 Demian pulseaudio[3643]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 21:36:34 Demian pulseaudio[3643]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 21:36:36 Demian pulseaudio[3713]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 21:36:36 Demian pulseaudio[3713]: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/cookie': No existe el fichero o el directorio
Dec 20 21:37:22 Demian pulseaudio[3950]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
```

Comment: Have you tried all the non-linuxy things already? Speakers are indeed working? Have you tried another set? Changed cables?

Comment: Is a portatil Acer mini A0725.

Comment: In addition to @Lix's comment, does the sound work if you reboot back into the old kernel? What version did you upgrade from? (You can dig that out of /var/log/dpkg.log.) Is this Debian Jessie/Testing or Unstable (it certainly doesn't sound like Squeeze or Wheezy)? How exactly does the sound "not work"? Have you verified that all mixer levels are correctly set and that no unexpected output channels are muted?

Comment: That "speaker-test" invocation result is useful information. Can you do it again though with `LC_ALL=C speaker-test -l 3 -t sine -c 1`? (Adding the `LC_ALL=C` at the beginning.) I *think* I know what the error messages mean but I prefer not having to guess, and that should give them in English with no attempts at translation.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling you wanna that I run the command: `LC_ALL = C speaker-test -l 3 -t sine -c 1?`, becouse not works. Sorry if I don't understand and my Debian is in Spanish.

Comment: No, just put `LC_ALL=C` (no spaces in there!) as one word before the command you did run and posted the result of in your question. It will cause the output to be in English, which is easier for a lot of people on this site to understand. That is, instead of `speaker-test -l 3 -t sine -c 1`, run `LC_ALL=C speaker-test -l 3 -t sine -c 1` (which you should be able to copy and paste from here into a terminal window)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I get it: `speaker-test 1.0.27.2

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Sine wave rate is 440.0000Hz
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Access denied

Playback open error: -111,Connection refused`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found the solution :

```
rm -r  /home/user/.pulse*
```

And change the file `/etc/libao.conf`

change(old)

```
default_driver=alsa
quiet
```

to (new )

```
default_driver=pulse
quiet
```

and restart your system.

Answer (score 0):

Please try a re-install of pulse

1. sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
2. sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
3. sudo alsa force-reload

followed by a reboot.

A PID check like

```
sudo fuser -v /dev/dsp* /dev/snd/*
```

should then produce something like this:

```
                     BEN.        PID ZUGR.  BEFEHL
/dev/snd/controlC0:  <user>      3985 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p:   <user>      3985 F...m pulseaudio
```

Comment: You should not post localized error messages. You can avoid this via temporarily setting the environment variable `LC_ALL` for the command, e.g. `LC_ALL=C fuser -v ...`.